# Module build failed: Error: Typescript emitted no output for node-modules/library/index.ts

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I have the following build chain: typescript+webpack. 
I try to inlcude a library (OpenDolphin) the following way: `import { OpenDolphin} from 'OpenDolphin';`

If I try to build this with webpack I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./~/OpenDolphin/index.ts
Module build failed: Error: Typescript emitted no output for /<MYPROJECTPATH>/node_modules/OpenDolphin/index.ts
    at Object.loader (/<MYPROJECTPATH>/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js:456:15)
 @ ./src/app.ts 6:20-42
```

I saw several posts from people with a similar problem, in most cases it was fixed with removing index.d.ts from the resolve part. It seems to me, that my case is a little different, since the library uses index.ts (without .d).

My webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.ts',
    output: {
        filename: './dist/main.js'
    },
    // Turn on sourcemaps
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    // Add minification
    // plugins: [
    //     new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    // ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts' }
        ]
    }
};
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

I have following questions:

- How can I fix this error? Has the library (OpenDolphin) the wrong structure?
- What is the correct structure of a "ts-node_module"?
- Whats the difference of index.ts and index.d.ts for node_modules? I tried to rename the index.ts to index.d.ts but then everything kind of exploded...